# EJB: percolating exceptions with "private" root causes

Tags: jakarta-ee, exception, ejb, ejb-3.0

Consider this scenario:

1. A stateless session bean is called remotely (from a different application, perhaps even running on  a different server):

   ```
   public void test() throws MyPublicException {
       // ... Business logic
       try {
           someDependency.perform();
       } catch (Exception ex) {
           // "ex" may be an instance of "MyPrivateException"
           throw new MyPublicException("Exception encountered", ex);
       }
   }
   ```
2. `MyPublicException` is a formal part of the bean's public API. It is available in the caller's classloader.
3. `MyPrivateException` is **not** not a part of the bean's public API. It is instantiated and thrown by some internal code that the bean eventually calls during business logic processing.

So, now that the container propagates the exception back to the caller, there's a small problem. The exception's root cause is of the type `MyPrivateException`, which is not available in the caller's classloader.

My question is - are there best practices as to what to do in such situations? the only thing I could come up with is to catch each exception inside the bean's method, and constructing an equivalent exception *without* the root cause. That, however, is a burden as it requires quite a bit of code.

Any other ideas?